# Identity functorial sparse matrix, Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

I'm trying to map 2 algorithms as vectors, instead of mapping true vectors.
Something similar can be done using CWiseNullaryOp, but i need a sparse version of it, so using functors and mapping them later is optimal, in my opinion.

I tried with the following program, but it doesn't wrok:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;


class index_class {
public:
    int operator() (int index) { // only reading mode
        return index;
    }
};

class one_class {
public:
    int operator() (int index) { // only reading mode
        return 1;
    }
};


int main(){

    int size = 4;
    int nnz = 4;

    one_class nnz_functor; // All values are 1
    index_class col_functor; // Column indices
    index_class row_functor; // Row pointers

    // Map the vectors and functors into a double sparse matrices 
    // as I need to multiply this by other double matrices
    Map< SparseMatrix<double,RowMajor,int> > mat (size, size, nnz, row_functor, col_functor, nnz_functor);

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor for [`Eigen::Map`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) as you used it. Map takes an already existing object and maps it to some other layout. As far as I understand you are trying to put values from some algorithms into an `Eigen::SparseMatrix`. Have you considered first collecting the results of your algorithms and then making them into an `Eigen::SparseMatrix` using [`setFromTriplets()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#a8f09e3597f37aa8861599260af6a53e0)?

```
std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>> values; // list of non-zero algorithm values

for (...) { // however you iterate over the algorithms
    double value = ... // however the values are generated
    values.emplace_back(index_row, index_col, value);
}
 
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor mat(size, size);

mat.setFromTriplets(values.begin(), values.end()); // create the SparseMatrix from the Triplets
```

Maybe you can use `NullaryExpr`:

```
auto values = Matrix<Triplet<double>, Dynamic, Dynamic>::NullaryExpr(size, size, [&](Index i, Index j){
    double value = ...; // however you want to get your value 
    return Triplet<double>{row_functor(i), col_functor(j), value};
}).eval();
Map<Vector<Triplet<double>, Dynamic>> vectorValues(values.data(), values.size());
SparseMatrix<double> mat(size, size);

mat.setFromTriplets(vectorValues.begin(), vectorValues.end());
```

Otherwise please specify your question a bit and provide a specific example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to not store any value. I want the nnz_array of the sparse matrix, for example, to point to an expression which return a value for each index you give to it. That will both speed the performance, as a simple algorithm is stored in cache instead of 2GB array, and the memory consumption too

Comment: so you would want to have something like ```algorithm(sparse_matrix)```? and when should the values be computed from the given indices? and do you already have the creation of the sparse matrix?

Comment: I want the sparse matrix to point to classes with the same api of vectors (which are the objects required from sparse matrices). When you ask the i-th element of that array of the sparse matrix, t just computes or returns it

Comment: this smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The sparse matrix cannot point to data, it can own it `Eigen::SparseMatrix<Object>` where `Object` is the type of data. then when you multiply this sparse matrix by some other values, the `Object` values will not be evaluated. But it is still unclear what exactly you want to do, can you provide a concrete small example?